# Spring batch keeps writing record after exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job where I have to check if the id is equal in all the file lines and should skip the lines that contains a different id . What I did is save the first record and then compare the id of each line, if the id is different then throw a Runtime exception, but for some reason spring batch works until it gets the line "to be excluded" and then repeats the writing process by writing all the records on exception .
here's what i mean :

```
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
2021-06-03 11:12:28.466 ERROR 41416 --- [   scheduling-1] tn.itserv.batch.SkipLinesListener        : An error occured while writing the input Force rollback on skippable exception so that skipped item can be located.
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=5598661]
sms [ Id_Campaign=7798661]
```

My step:

```
    @Bean
    public Step loadFiles() throws IOException {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step1")
                .<FileModelIn, FileModelOut>chunk(100)
                .reader(multiResourceItemReader())
                .processor(batchProcessor())
                .writer(batchWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(skipLinesListener())
                .noRetry(RuntimeException.class)
                .noRollback(RuntimeException.class)
                .listener(MyStepListner())
                .build();
    }
```

SkipPolicy:

```
public class SkipLinesListener implements SkipPolicy {
    private static final int MAX_SKIP_COUNT = 10;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SkipLinesListener.class);

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable t, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
        if (t instanceof  RuntimeException && skipCount < MAX_SKIP_COUNT )
        { RuntimeException ex=(RuntimeException)t;
            logger.error("An error occured while writing the input "+ ex.getMessage());
            return true;
        }
        if (t instanceof FlatFileParseException && skipCount < MAX_SKIP_COUNT ) {
            FlatFileParseException ex = (FlatFileParseException) t;
           
         logger.error("An error occured while processing the "+ ex.getInput());
                return true;     
        }
    
    return false;
    
    }

}
```

I don't know why am getting this behaviour, am I missing something?
am throwing the exception in the itemwriter class

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends FileModelOut> items) throws Exception {
        List<FCCampaignModel> campaigns=new ArrayList<FCCampaignModel>();   
        List<sms> smsList=new ArrayList<>();
        FCCampaignModel firstLine=cmsDaoProxy.addCampaign(items.get(0).getFcCampaignModel());
        
        for (FileModelOut fileContent : items) {
         if (fileContent.getFcCampaignModel().getId_Campaign().equals(firstLine.getId_Campaign()))
            {
             
            smsRepository.save(fileContent.getSms());
            }
         else throw new RuntimeException("different id campaign detected : "+fileContent.getFcCampaignModel().getId_Campaign());
         
        }
```

Comment: Please attach the code where you're throwing the RuntimeException. Add some more logs above to identify the pattern of the error. What's the behaviour you're expecting? I can see you have used a skip logic.

Comment: i edited it and  added the part where i threw the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is declared as a skippable exception, so when it is thrown from the item writer, Spring Batch will scan the chunk item by item, ie re-process items one by one, each one in its own transaction.

This is because items are written in chunks (ie in bulk mode), and if an exception occurs during that bulk-write operation, Spring Batch cannot know which item caused the issue, so it will retry them one by one. You can find an example in the samples module: [Chunk Scanning Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#chunk-scanning-sample).

Comment: what i understood is that this is normal behvior, so is there a way to prevent re-processing items one by one and just continue writing the chunk after the exception ? because if the items are processed one by one `if(fileContent.getFcCampaignModel().getId_Campaign().equals(firstLine.getId_Campaign()))  is going to be always true `

Comment: No, there is an open feature request for that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/2071. But your case is really specific: `I have to check if the id is equal in all the file lines and should skip the lines that contains a different id`: what you are doing in the writer should be done in an item processor. Filtering data (which you seem to call skip) is a typical use case for an item processor. You did not share your actual problem with an example of input data, but it seems that your skip policy is not suitable for the use case.

Comment: so i should move the id check part to the processor that makes sense now thank you so much